# pyspark creates output file as folder

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Pyspark creates folder instead of file. For the below command, it creates an empty folder with name proto.parquet in the directory.

```
df.write.parquet("output/proto.parquet")
```

Tried with csv and other formats, but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Spark creates a folder instead of a file is the expected behavior. The reason being that Spark is a distributed system, hence data is processed in partitions and each worker node will write out its data to a part file.

So what you are seeing is the way it should work. It works the same way with mapreduce.

Comment: The folder is empty

Comment: How can I get the file as csv? Should I change anything?

Comment: First of all, make sure you have data in your DataFrame. What happens when you do a df.show()?

Comment: Which cluster manager are you using? Standalone? Spark on Yarn? Don't use a relative path.  Be explicit to test which means include the first slash, i.e. df.write.format("text").save("/user/output/test")

Comment: standalone mode

Comment: Also, you can specify hdfs:/// or file:///

Comment: If you are using standalone then it defaults to local file system. Make sure your user has appropriate permissions. Create a folder in /tmp and give it enough permissions for whatever user you are running pyspark under. Then save your data there .save("/tmp/output/test")

Comment: @xmorere I am able to write using pandas, `pd_df.to_csv('File.csv',index = False)`  Buth this(`df.write.parquet`) dont help