# pyspark df.write fails on file creation

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop

When writing a dataframe, pyspark creates the directory, creates a temporary dir that directory, but no files.  csv & parquet formats return similar errors.  It fails with:

````
```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o99.save: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    ... 41 more```
````

My Code:

````
```
output_path = ".data/output/FireIncidents/"


# fire_df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(output_path)# fails, makes folder but no files.  
# fire_df.write.parquet(output_path,  mode='overwrite')  # fails creates folder by no file. 
# fire_df.write.csv(output_path, mode='overwrite')  # fails, makes folder but no files. 
# fire_df.write.save(output_path,format='parquet')  # fails, makes folder but no files. 
# fire_df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("tab1")  # fails, makes folder but no files. 
# fire_df.select("incident_number","call_datetime","incident_address").write.save("namesAndFavColors.parquet") # from the documentation, same effect
df_writer = pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter(fire_df)
df_writer = df_writer.saveAsTable('test', format='parquet', mode='overwrite',path=output_path)

type(fire_df) ==pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

fire_df.select('incident_number', 'call_datetime','incident_address').show()
```+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|incident_number|       call_datetime|    incident_address|
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     18-0032836|2018/09/06 12:13:...|  16888 RIVERVIEW ST|
|     19-0019239|2019/06/03 06:46:...| 18469 GREENVIEW AVE|
|     20-0010724|2020/04/05 10:44:...|        2930 CODY ST|
```
etc.
````

Docs: <https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

---

I've tried all the variations above, multiple formats, more that one version of Hadoop,

HADOOP_HOME== "c:\hadoop"

hadoop  3.2.1 and or 3.2.2 (tried both)
pyspark 3.2.0

Similar SO question, without resolution.
[pyspark creates output file as folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216681/pyspark-creates-output-file-as-folder)
(note the comment where the requestor notes that created dir is empty.)

Comment: Typically, I've seen `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when you're not using the correct Java version. E.g. Spark 3.2 requires Java 8 or 11, and no later

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=UnsatisfiedLinkError%20spark

Comment: I have Java 8.0.3110.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like windows native IO libraries is absent.

> Hadoop requires native libraries on Windows to work properly -that includes to access the file:// filesystem, where Hadoop uses some Windows APIs to implement posix-like file access permissions.
>
> This is implemented in HADOOP.DLL and WINUTILS.EXE
>
> In particular, %HADOOP_HOME%\BIN\WINUTILS.EXE must be locatable.
>
> If it is not, Hadoop or an application built on top of Hadoop will fail.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems

And [winutils repo](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils)

Comment: This is correct even if you already have winutils.exe & the Environment Var setup.  I needed the additional files found in @Egor s second link.  Although, while I no longer get the error message, I've only been able to write to CSV. Writing to Parquet creates no files, but also no longer returns the error.

Comment: HADOOP_HOME must be defined as a SYSTEM variable, not as a USER variable, and %HADOOP_HOME%\BIN must be in the SYSTEM Path, not a user Path.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are not getting the `java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.` error tells me that you have your `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable setup.

If the `HADOOP_HOME` directory does **not** have a "bin" subdirectory that contains the `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` files, IIRC, you get a different error.

**Tangent/FYI**: When I was trying to figure out how to get those 2 Windows binaries, I tried these 3 locations:

1. https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/  (up through v3.0.0)
2. https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/   (the new spot; I'm on PySpark 3.2.1 and I picked the 3.2.2 build (the latest as of 2022-01-29).)
3. https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils/   (this had more recent builds, but I didn't end up using them)

So based on the above, I expect that what you're lacking is the `$env:HADOOP_HOME\bin` folder being in your `PATH`. I ran this at an elevated Powershell prompt, then restarted my environment (VsCode). After that, I was able to save Parquet files as expected.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$env:PATH;$env:HADOOP_HOME\bin", "Machine")
```

And one last bit of context, here's the Python code I was testing with; the .csv was nothing special.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.read.options(header=True).csv("baseline-test.csv")
sdf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("baseline-test-parquet")
```